# USB Installation reports disk full

Tags: system-installation

When installing ubuntu 12.10 via live usb, message pops up reporting partition is full. I wasn't even given an option to select the partition I want to use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you get at the page asking you if you want to install Ubuntu alongside an other OS, you should check the **Something Else** option in order to enter the GParted tool. That way you can see what's going on with your disk.